# Typeset process stops at "ts1cmr.fd" - Issue resolved - \MakeUppercase vs. \uppercase

Tags: errors, compilation-error, texworks, uppercase

UPDATE: I discovered "\MakeUppercase" vs. "\uppercase" was the root cause of the issue. Issue resolved.

I have been successfully compiling this document for a while. The file has been a work in progress over the years. I use all sorts of packages, fonts, and commands. I use TeXworks and MiKTeX. It was working fine until the typesetting process begun to stop at the following line item:

C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd

The console generates a few warnings before this line item, which I usually ignore, unless it stops the file. The actual stoppage happens at the above ts1cmr.fd line item.

Before I really start to debug the details of my file **Does anyone know what the ts1cmr.fd file is or why the typesetting halted at it?** I search engined for it, but couldn't find anything helpful. I reinstalled TeXworks and MiKTeX - it did nothing.

[image]

Comment: It's a font definition (`.fd`) file. `ts1` is the encoding. `cmr` is the family. It is safe to say that whatever is causing your error, it is not this file. Possibly you should not ignore the warnings?!

Comment: It doesn't look as if it stops at the file, it has been read. Something after it is the problem.

Comment: Good news! I found the cause of the problem. I was at a standstill without your answers. So, thank you!

The "\MakeUppercase" command was causing the file to just stop. (No error or anything.) After changing "\MakeUppercase" to "\uppercase" I got it to work fine. I just learned about some of the technical differences between the two, but it's safe to say I don't need "\MakeUppercase" here. I don't know why it caused an issue after previously working fine.